# Remove specific strings from dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have problem to clear the string "km/kg", "kmpl", "CC", and "bhp" from these column in dataset

Here is the example dataset

```
Year   | Fuel_Type | Mileage    | Engine  | Power     |
2010   | LPG       | 26.6 km/kg | 998 CC  | 58.16 bhp |
2011   | Diesel    | 19.67 kmpl | 1582 CC | 126.2 bhp |
```

In this particular case, remove all characters from Engine, Mileage and Power columns of the dataset so that only the number remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `df.replace` and use `regex` patterns for string match.

```
df[['Mileage','Engine','Power']] = df[['Mileage','Engine','Power']].replace(to_replace=r'([a-z/]+|[A-Z/]+)', value='', regex=True)
```

Prints:

```
  Year Fuel_Type  Mileage  Engine   Power
0  2010       LPG   26.6    998     58.16 
1  2011    Diesel  19.67    1582    126.2
```

Comment: Well this does it basically. Reading of the dataset + with regex (which makes it short & clean).

Comment: Yeah pandas makes it easy with application of regex in the string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [regular expression](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) to do this.

Here's a quick example on how you can do it. Also I assume you already **know** to **read** the dataset of yours right so what you can do is just take the column and iterate over it and apply that regex sample code I provided.

When it comes to reading data sets I personally love using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import re

l = ["26.6 km/kg","19.67 kmpl","998 CC","58.16 bhp"]


for i in l:
    t = re.sub(r'\D+$','',i)
    print(t)
```

**Output:**

```
26.6
19.67
998
58.16
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

If you're curious about `\D+$` , this is what it means

> \D    Returns a match where the string DOES NOT contain digits    "\D"

> The + sign basically means any occurrences of it 1 or more.

> $ means ends with

Read more about regular expressions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).

Comment: basically I assumed he knows how to read his data set. What I am trying to imply is that he can use regular expressions & with the example code is he can do it :)

Comment: This is a better regex expression that what I wrote.

Comment: @Rashal replace my regex expression with `\D+$`. This is more clean.